# Increased file size after sending to FTP using Apache Commons Net

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

I'm trying to send a file directly from sftp using [jcraft](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jcraft/jsch) to ftp server using [commons-net](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-net/commons-net)
Here is a small example of my code:

```
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = jsch.getSession("username", "sftp.server.address", 22);
    session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setPassword("password");
    session.connect();

    //connect to sftp
    Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
    channel.connect();
    ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;

    //connect to ftp
    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    ftpClient.connect("ftp.server.address", 21);
    ftpClient.login("username", "password");
    ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    ftpClient.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE); // maybe here is the problem :/

    //getting file as an inputstream from the sftp
    InputStream sftpFileInputStream = sftpChannel.get("/temp/file1");

    //sending sftp fileinputstream directry to the ftp server
    ftpClient.storeFile("file1", sftpFileInputStream);
    ftpClient.disconnect();

    sftpChannel.exit();
    session.disconnect();
```

The idea is very simple - connect simultaneously to the both servers, grab the file from the sftp server as an input stream and send it to the other ftp server. The code is working, **but the file has +2MB increased size after the sending**.
The big problem is that the file has no extension and I don't know what em I sending. 
I'm not sure if the file is damaged after sending and also I'm not sure what transfer mode should I have to use for files like that using the Apache commons net.

As I know the InputSteam is not affected by the file type, right? Little help for understanding what is going on would be appreciated...

I'm going to try to save the file as a temp file first and then send it to the ftp server. I will update the post for more information.

**Edit:** Downloading the file from the sftp into a temp file has no changes - the file has unchanged size. But again after sending to the ftp server using commons-net increases the file size with 2MB. After some tests I figured out that the problem is from sending the file - topic is changed to be more clear.

Here is more clear example:

```
//connect to ftp
    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    ftpClient.connect("ftp.server.address", 21);
    ftpClient.login("username", "password");

    //sending inputstream to the ftp server
    ftpClient.storeFile("data", new FileInputStream(new File("/data")));
    ftpClient.disconnect();
```

**Forgot to mention that the file is around 500MB** and as I said it has no extension.

**Update**:
With `IOUtils` there is no problem:

```
URL url = new URL("ftp://username:password@ftp.server.address/data");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();

FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("/data"));
OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
IOUtils.copy(fileInputStream, outputStream);
fileInputStream.close();
outputStream.close();
```

the file has the same size after the sent... Still can't understand what is happening under the hood in that FTPClient.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl After the download the file is exact same size as it has to be. But when I send it to the ftp server the file size is increased with around 2MB each time. Even if it is not a temp file it happens the same - the file has increased size.

Comment: Your *"more clear example"* does not show that you are using `BINARY_FILE_TYPE`.

Comment: It shows that in this situation I'm using the default - STREAM_TRANSFER_MODE. Changing the transfer mode has no effect.

Answer (score 3):

My mistake was that I was using `FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE` on `ftpClient.setFileTransferMode`... Thanks to [@Martin Prikryl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/850848/martin-prikryl) I saw it in my history. And also I'm not [alone in this mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218245/ftpclients-setfiletransfermode-not-taking-effect).
Here is the working example:

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
ftpClient.connect("ftp.server.address", 21);
ftpClient.login("username", "password");
ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
ftpClient.setFileTransferMode(FTP.STREAM_TRANSFER_MODE); 
ftpClient.storeFile("data", new FileInputStream(new File("/data")));
ftpClient.disconnect();
```

`ftpClient.setFileType` values are:

- **FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE** - default if the method is never called
- **FTP.EBCDIC_FILE_TYPE** - indicate the file(s) being transferred should
  be treated as EBCDIC
- **FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE** - indicate the file(s)
  being transferred should be treated as a binary image, i.e., no
  translations should be performed
- **FTP.LOCAL_FILE_TYPE** - indicate the
  file(s) being transferred should be treated as a local type

`ftpClient.setFileTransferMode` values are:

- **FTP.STREAM_TRANSFER_MODE** - the default transfer mode if this method is never called or if a connect method is called
- **FTP.BLOCK_TRANSFER_MODE** - indicate a file is to be transferred as a series of blocks
- **FTP.COMPRESSED_TRANSFER_MODE** - indicate a file is to be transferred as FTP compressed data

[Here is a link](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTP.html) from the documentation that could save me hours of testing.